# Integrate $ \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{Ax-\frac{x^2}{2}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

From online integral calculators I am aware that:

$$ \int_a^b\frac{1}{\sqrt{Ax-\frac{x^2}{2}}}dx=\sqrt{2}\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{A}-1\right)\right]\Bigg|_a^b$$

When I work backwards starting with: $$y=\sqrt{2}\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{x-A}{A}\right)\right]\Bigg |_a^b$$
$$=\sqrt{2}\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{A}-1\right)\right]\Bigg |_a^b$$

I can show that the integral is correct.

But how would I go about integrating the initial expression in the first place?

I can't think of any suitable substitution.

Comment: s or 2 in the integral?

Comment: @Ty. Sorry , it is a 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{x}$:
$$\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{A-\frac{u^2}{2}}} \; du$$
Then let $t=\frac{u}{\sqrt{2A}}$:
$$\int \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \; dt$$
$$2\sqrt{2}\arcsin{t}+C$$
$$2\sqrt{2}\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{2A}}\right)} \bigg \rvert_a^b$$
The expression that I have and the one that your integral calculator gave are equivalent.

Comment: Great , can I just ask how you went about finding the appropriate substitutions ?

Comment: This integral is different from that given in OP.

Comment: @Koro Its equivalent

Comment: @Kantura first substitution was to cancel an x in the radical and second substitution was to make the denominator $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ so it's the easy $\arcsin{t}$ integral.

Comment: @Ty. Oh yes. My bad 

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{Ax-\frac{x^2}{2}}}dx$$
$$=\int_a^b \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2Ax-x^2}}dx$$
$$=\sqrt 2\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2-(x-A)^2}}dx$$
$$=\sqrt 2\int_a^b \frac{d(x-A)}{\sqrt{A^2-(x-A)^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt 2\left[\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-A}{A}\right)\right]_a^b $$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\sqrt{2}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2Ax-x^2}}=\sqrt{2}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{A^2-(x-A)^2}}$$ Let $x-A=A \sin \theta$, then
$$\sqrt{2}\int_{\sin^{-1}(a-A)/A}^{\sin^{-1}(b-A)/A} \frac{A \cos \theta}{A \cos\theta} =\sqrt{2}\int_{\sin^{-1}(a-A)/A}^{\sin^{-1}(b-A)/A} d\theta$$
$$\implies I=\sqrt{2}[\sin^{-1}((b-A)/A)- \sin^{-1}((a-A)/A)]$$